# What means @ in prefs.yml (vagrant config)

Tags: vagrant, yaml

Yesterday I had issue with setup vagrant. Vagrant config was created by devops. This is part of `prefs.yml` file

```
vms:
  trinidad:
    memory: 1536
    domains:
      - trinidad.dev
    mounts:
      trinidad@: trinidad
```

I noticed 1 interesting thing - using symbol `@` in mounts section.
I tried to find what it meant. One thing, which I found - this is sentence from [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) - Two additional sigil characters are reserved in YAML for possible future standardisation: the at sign ( @ ) and accent grave ( ` ).

And nothing more. Our devops tried to explain me that this symbol uses for node.js, but I didn't understand him, because he explained in very strange way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `@` is a reserved character in YAML, it is only so as a [directive indicator](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2774228) (scroll a bit up from the example). Which means that it has to come **at the beginning** of a scalar (and you can quote the scalar if it starts with `@`: `"@some_scalar"`).

In your example the `@` is not special for YAML, and the key `trinidad@` is handed to vagrant as is and, if at all, interpreted there (I have not found any documentation that shows it is).

Comment: I also did not found, and I want to know, what the reason of using @ in postfix way.